# Cross references without labels

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

In word 2010, I can insert cross references of Figures, like `Figure 1`, `Figure 2`, etc.

How I can show only the number of the cross references ? to get some similar to

Figures `1`, `2` and `3`.

Comment: Nice question. I had the same problem. I added a completely different answer, which tells you what I found experts do.

Answer (score 3):

In Word 2016 it worked for me if I:

- Step 1: Insert caption and click "Exclude Label from caption"
- Step 2: Insert cross-reference to that figure.
- Step 3: In the line above the figure number type in "Figure " then
  hit delete

This gives you a cross-reference that refreshes appropriately if the number changes, and doesn't add "Figure " to the beginning if you refresh it (select and press F9) (If you just delete "Figure " from the field code, it comes back when you refresh).

Caveats:

- If you insert a new figure cross-reference, it will have "Figure " in it again.
- I noticed that the two codes now have different reference numbers when you click on "Edit Field". For example, "1" on its own is REF  _Ref480891584 \h , whereas from then on if I insert a figure, it's "Figure 1" REF  _Ref480892012 \h
- I didn't check if this stays the same after saving, closing, and re-opening the file.

Answer (score 1):

In case you already have your captions set up, or only need to suppress the label in particular positions, you can use [this suggestion by Word MVP Stefan Blom](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/how-to-display-figure-number-only-in-cross/02ae3cd0-6c3c-401d-990c-5220d7f0be1e) on the Microsoft Community Answers Forum.

> After you have inserted the cross-reference, add a so-called numeric picture switch to specify a number format. To do that, press `Alt`+`F9` to toggle display of field codes; you'll find that the cross-references are REF fields. Add # "0" to the end of the relevant REF fields. Press `Alt`+`F9` again to hide the codes, and press F9 to update fields in the selection.

Rather than using `ALT`+`F9`, you can also right click and select 'Edit field'. Depending on your version of Word, you might need to toggle 'Field codes' at the lower left of the dialog window to access and change the field code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also select multiple figures and then insert cross-reference and it will automatically do Figures 1,2 and 3.

Comment: I've just tried, hoping this would work, but it doesn't seem to. Could you provide further instructions / details on this?

Comment: I am facing the same problem and I could not believe that it should be that simple. So I tried to select multiple figures in the "Insert cross reference" dialog, but I could not do so. The selection field does not allow multiple selections but is single-select.  @michthan How do you do that?

Comment: @user2690527 I think this was possible in a previous version of Microsoft Word, but not anymore. I just tried it myself, and I wasn't able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the built-in creator of captions, do what experts do to have a more reliable and flexible experience:

(Except when I write "Rodolfo:" the text comes from https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008180_Numbering_with_Sequence_Fields.html I might have edited the text when I store in my Office knowledge base document.)

1. Position the insertion point where you want the sequential number to appear. For instance, this would be in the caption for the table or figure.
2. Press **Ctrl+F9** to insert field brackets. Make sure the insertion point stays between the brackets.
3. Type **"seq "** followed by the name of the element. This name is up to you, but should be the same for each item in this sequence. For instance, you could type "**seq figures**" or "**seq tables**" (without the quote marks).
4. Press **F9** to update the field information. Word replaces the field with the next number in the sequence you have specified.
5. If you want a period, tab, or some other character after the number, enter it after the number generated by the SEQ field.
6. Select everything you created in steps 1 through 5.
7. Press **Alt+F3**. Word displays the Create New Building Block dialog box.

   [image: Create New Building Block dialog box]
8. In the Name field enter a name by which you want this highlighted text known. This should be something short and meaningful, such as NumList or even NL (Rodolfo: or nF if you are numbering figures).
9. Click on the OK button. The dialog box closes.
10. Now whenever you want to insert the number, type the name you defined in step 7, and then press the **F3** key. The field is entered in the document. Note that the number always shows up as 1, but it is updated when you print, or when you select the entire list and press **F9**.
11. The process described in this tip works best if you have a single list in your document. Note that the sequence field starts at the beginning of the document and numbers through the whole document, based on the identifier you use. If you are going to have multiple lists in your document, then you can add a second AutoText entry to help with this. (Rodolfo: You may want the list to restart with number 1, e.g., in the next chapter. I would take care of this after finishing the writing. To have each chapter begin with, for example, Figure 1, I’d modify the field with the number of the first figure by adding **\r1**). The only difference in the above steps is that the SEQ field you define would look like **{ seq NumList \r1 }**. The addition of the \r1 switch causes Word to start the sequence counter over at 1. You would use this whenever you wanted to start a new list, and use the regular field for the rest of your numbered items. (If you want to start the list over at a number other than 1, use the starting number right after **\r**.)
12. Rodolfo: You’d better create another building block to create (or replace and existing field) as in the previous point 11. You can name it as 1F. (I suggested that the name of the Quick Part of any figure after the first of each chapter be nF because the number of such figures can be created with the field **{ seq NumList \n }**). The **\n** argument is not needed because is the default. However, I would use it to make naming more clear and possibly make the updating quicker because, usually, the more explicit you are, the computer has to think less.
13. Rodolfo: To update field, select the whole document with **Ctrl + A** (A for All). Or just select the portion you need or want to update. Then press **F9** to update the field information.

**Cross References to the created numbers (by Rodolfo Oviedo)**

A. Create a **Marker**

1. Select the number you want to cross reference
2. Ribbon – Insert – Links – Bookmarks
3. Choose a meaningful name
4. Add

B. **Cross reference** to the marker

1. Place the cursor where you want to insert the cross reference to the number
2. Ribbon – References – Captions – Cross-reference – Reference type: Bookmark
3. Choose the name chosen while creating the marker
4. Insert

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the switch # 0.0 in the cross referencing field.  It is that simple!

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: This duplicates an earlier answer with the switch # 0.